# More than one protocol in a type constraint

Tags: swift, generics

I want to use a generic typed class and a type constraint:

```
class MyCustomClass<T : Equatable> {
  var a: Array<T>
  init() {
    a = Array<T>()
  }
}
```

That works fine. But what happens if I want to use a second protocol, f.e.

```
class MyCustomClass<T : Equatable, IndexableBase> {
  var a: Array<T>
  init() {
    a = Array<T>()
  }
}
```

It says that the initializer fails because I have to use 2 instead of 1 argument. That I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this workaround

```
class MyCustomClass<T: Equatable where T: IndexableBase > {
    var a: Array<T>
    init() {
        a = Array<T>()
    }
}
```

Swift 4:

```
class MyCustomClass<T: Equatable> where T: Collection  {
    var a: Array<T>
    init() {
        a = Array<T>()
    }
}
```

Comment: The where operator works perfect for me (Xcode 8.1, Swift 3) so I'm using this solution.

Comment: @altralaser Even if this "works" for you in Swift 3, it should give you a warning, namely [**emphasis** mine]: _"warning: '`where`' clause next to generic parameters **is deprecated and will be removed in the future version of Swift**"_. So you probably want to use a solution that is up to date with Swift 3, or your implementation will be broken in a future update of Swift (see the other two answers for Swift 3-up-to-date versions).

Comment: @dfri, aaaaaaand its broken in swift 4.

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 3**

*(I've replaced [`IndexableBase`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/indexablebase) with `Collection` in your example, you should prefer the latter)*

---

As per Swift 3, protocol composition use the infix operator `&` over the previous `protocol<...>` construct, as described in the accepted and implemented evolution proposal:

- [SE-0095: Replace `protocol<P1,P2>` syntax with `P1 & P2` syntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0095-any-as-existential.md)

Hence, using protocol composition you may place the combined type constraint at the `T` placeholder in the parameter list:

```
class MyCustomClass<T: Equatable & Collection> { /* ... */ }
```

---

As an alternative to protocol composition, you could also make use of `where` clause to join several type (and subtype) constraint. As per the accepted and implemented evolution proposal:

- [Se-0081: Move where clause to end of declaration](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0081-move-where-expression.md)

the `where` clause has been moved to end of the declaration, in which case your example would read:

```
class MyCustomClass<T: Equatable> where T: Comparable { /* ... */ }
```

or, even place the full protocol composition with the `where` clause at the end of the declaration

```
class MyCustomClass<T> where T: Equatable & Comparable { /* ... */ }
```

---

***What style should we prefer?***

The interesting discussion is what we should consider "best practice", as this particular subject is not specified Swift API guidelines. Do we place

- all (main type) constraints in the parameter list, or
- all constraints at the end of the declaration, or
- split up constraints with some in the parameter list and others placed at the end of the declaration?

Consider the following contrived example, where we have a construct a protocol that we plan to use as a type constraint (`Doable`), which in itself holds an `associatedtype` to which we may place a type constraint.

```
protocol Doable { 
    associatedtype U
}
```

Using the different methods above, all the following three alternatives are valid, syntactically

```
// alternative #1
func foo<T: Equatable & Doable>(_ bar: T) -> () where T.U: Comparable { /* ... */ }

// alternative #2
func foo<T: Equatable>(_ bar: T) -> () where T: Doable, T.U: Comparable { /* ... */ }

// alternative #3
func foo<T>(_ bar: T) -> () where T: Equatable & Doable, T.U: Comparable { /* ... */ }
```

I'll quote Apple dev Joe Groff from [the evolution thread that that brought forth SE-0081](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160404/014337.html):

> It's a judgment call. It's my feeling that in many cases, a generic
>   parameter is constrained by at least one important protocol or base
>   class that's worth calling out up front, so it's reasonable to allow
>   things like
>
> ```
> func foo<C: Collection>(x: C) -> C.Element
> ```
>
> without banishing the `Collection` constraint too far from the front
>   of the declaration.

So in the contrived example above, it might be appropriate to use protocol composition for the type constraints that apply directly to the generic placeholder `T`, and place these constraints in the parameter list, whereas the subtype constraint of `T.U` is placed at the end of the declaration. Namely, alternative #1 above.

Comment: This is impressive! but what do you think about [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0081-move-where-expression.md)? I answered based on it... btw I'm not the downvoter, I'm the upvoter :)

Comment: @AhmadF Thanks. That proposal is also included in my answer, and I believe it's just as relevant as the new protocol composition (two parts of the same concept). The interesting discussion is what we should consider best practice, as it's not really specified in the Swift API guidelines. Do we place all constraints at the end of the declaration, or just subtype constraints? There's an interesting discussion tied to the evolution proposal SE-0081 that contains some thoughts and the pros and cons of where to put different constraints; I'll include a little bit of this discussion in my answer.

Comment: To be honest I find <T: Equatable & Collection> is "cooler", I didn't know that it's exist!